# logging in via passport by an express server on top of nodejs, using mongoose to connect with mongoDB

Tags: express, authentication, mongoose, passport.js, bcrypt

I am quite new to authentication and authorization and I am trying to sign in and register user to access my api. I managed to do the registration handler and store user info and Bcrypt it successfully. but I am still having difficulty accessing them to sign them in by my login endpoint handler.
here is the code I have written up to now.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config();
}
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require('express-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const middle = require('./middlewares/middleware');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const usersDb = require('./db/db');
const initializePassport = require('./passport-config');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error));
db.once('open', () => console.log('DATABASE IS AVAILABLE'));

initializePassport(
  passport,
  (name) => usersDb.find((user) => user.name === name),
  (password) => usersDb.find((user) => user.password === password)
);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(flash());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
//   try {
//     users = await usersDb.find();
//     res.json(users);
//   } catch (err) {
//     res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
//   }
// });

app.get('/', middle.checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs', { name: req.user.name }, { users });
});

app.get('/login', middle.checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('login.ejs');
});

app.post(
  '/login',
  middle.checkNotAuthenticated,
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true,
  })
);

app.get('/register', middle.checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('register.ejs');
});

app.post('/register', middle.checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    user = await new usersDb({
      name: req.body.name,
      password: hashedPassword,
      score: req.body.score,
      dateSignedUp: req.body.dateSignedUp,
      lastPlayed: req.body.lastPlayed,
    });
    user.save(function (err, user) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(`user ${user.name} registered successfully`);
    });
    res.redirect('/login');
  } catch {
    res.redirect('/register');
  }
});

app.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logOut();
  res.redirect('/login');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and here is the passport-config file content

```
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const usersDb = require('./db/db');

function initialize(passport, getUserByName) {
  const authenticateUser = async (name, password, done) => {
    const user = usersDb.findOne({ name: name });
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'no user with that name' });
    }
    try {
      if (
        await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
          result = true;
        })
      ) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'password incorrect' });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e);
    }
  };

  passport.use(new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'name' }, authenticateUser));

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
}

module.exports = initialize;
```

As far as I debugged it up to now I can not communicate with DB when I am asking

```
        const user = usersDb.findOne({ name: name });
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you so much for going through all the code.

Answer (score 0):

So you can add a promise after looking for the name so it will wait for result and store it in respone

> usersDb.findOne({ name: name })
> .then(user => console.log(user)) // it will log result

Another way is you could pass a function:

> usersDb.findOne({ name: name }, (err, result) => {
> if (err) throw err;
>
> if (!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'no user with that name' });
>
> //here you can add the rest of code to chick if password is correct
>
> })

Comment: I am using This for both of them actually
const usersDb = require('./db/db');

Comment: I hope that helps let me know.